# .htaccess URL redirection without filename

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I Have an issue with the redirection of my PHP page.

My concern is I have a page named "page.php" that also contains some parameters during redirection.

> www.exampleurl.com/page/param-1

in these url, the Parameters are like this

```
Array
{
   [0] => www.exampleurl.com  //URL
   [1] => page  //page.php page where the page will redirect
   [2] => param-1  //GET parameter for page.php
}
```

And the Redirection is properly done on page.php with parameters

But I Need the URL Like This

> www.exampleurl.com/param-1

Using this URL, I required it still redirect to page.php instead of this URL do not have "page/" and only have parameters. or if someone wants to request the page named "page.php", I don't need of "page/" but the page want to redirect on page.php

Rules for .htaccess I am Using

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1                   [R=301,L]

# not rewrite css, js and images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpg|gif|png)$           [NC]
RewriteRule  ^page/(.*)$/?$         page.php?slug=$1            [NC,L]
```

What the changes I have required?

Comment: you can set your domain to your desired directory in `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

Add after your rewrites in .htaccess this rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Rewrite example: /param-1 to /page.php?slug=param-1